# How to simulate Paste in a WPF TextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, onpaste

I have a TextBox in my WPF application which I've added a Paste event to using:

```
DataObject.AddPastingHandler(elm, new DataObjectPastingEventHandler(OnPaste));
```

Now I want to trigger the OnPaste event from C# code. How can I do this? I tried calling the Paste() function on the control. The text is pasted in the control, but the OnPaste event is not triggered..:

```
private static void Foo(TextBox textBox, string pastedText)
{
    Clipboard.SetData(DataFormats.Text, pastedText);
    textBox.Paste();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Invoke the ApplicationCommand [Paste](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.applicationcommands.paste.aspx):

```
ApplicationCommands.Paste.Execute(this, pastedText)
```

Please note that this will not work in partial trust!

Comment: Thx. The code I suggested in the question actually works too.. My bad. Problem was that the pasting handler must be set manually, and I set it in some part of the code that wasn't triggered in my unit test..

Answer (score 1):

You could do it via reflection. You need to find the private delegate field, then invoke it.

See [How to: Hook Up a Delegate Using Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228976.aspx).